# Intercept Default field values

Tags: magento2.3, sku, default-values

Talking about [Default Field Values](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-fields-autogenerated.html), I'd like to intercept and edit those autogenerated values.

I'd like to do this for:

- Sku
- URL key

---

E.g.

Product name: **My Beautiful Product**

Autogenerated SKU: **m-btfl-prdct**

Autogenerated URL key: **my-beautiful-product-download**

---

#### How can I achieve this?

I tried to edit `Magento_Catalog/js/components/import-handler`

Located in: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/import-handler.js`

but without any result.